I'm having issues importing/adding Selenium as an external library to my (Intelij) JavaFX project
I'm trying to utilize selenium in a web automation software that I'm developing with JAVA, the following is a snippet of what I'm trying to execute using Intelij as the code editor:
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Set the path to the chromedriver executable
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");

        // Initialize a ChromeDriver instance
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        // Open a webpage
        driver.get("https://github.com/login");

        // Perform any additional actions here
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        WebElement name_query = driver.findElement(By.name("login"));
        System.out.println("Enter your username:");
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        name_query.sendKeys(name);

        WebElement password_query = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
        System.out.println("Enter your password:");
        String password = sc.nextLine();
        password_query.sendKeys(password);

        WebElement submit_btn = driver.findElement(By.name("commit"));
        submit_btn.click(); 

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Close the browser
        driver.quit();

        sc.close();
    }
}

Am I doing something wrong?
The project is a maven project that utilizes POM files so I've tried adding it in manually as a dependency in my pom.xml file using the following code snippet:
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.21.0</version>
        </dependency>

When I try the following code snippet in my main Java file, none of the required segments work as they are highlighted in red.
Here's the module-info content:
module com.example.seleniumjavafxtest {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;


    opens com.example.seleniumjavafxtest to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.seleniumjavafxtest;
}


Why is this tagged JavaFX? There seems to be no JavaFX content.

"none of the required segments work as they are highlighted in red" Those are compile errors. What do the error messages say?

The errors state that the library I've imported does not exist eventhough it does, how do I fix the issue here?

Is it a modular project?

Yes, it is a modular project.

Post your module-info.java file.

I've updated the post to include it's content.

You need to require the module(s) for Selenium. I don’t know if Selenium is modular (with explicitly named modules) or non-modular (in which case you will have to determine the automatic module names). I don’t know the module names in either case, but it should be pretty easy to find them in the documentation.

Sure, I’ll update the post if I’ve found a solution to it. Thank you!

I sorted the issue out at found that there were a few missing dependencies in the pom.xml file, simply include the latest maven dependency for selenium in your xml file like so:
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.21.0</version>
    <!--The version varies based on it's current version-->
</dependency>

You can visit the following site to see the latest versions available: Selenium Dependency Repo
Furthermore in the modules-info page, ensure that you add selenium as a required dependency.
